# Como exportar dentro do subGrid?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jqgrid

**Informações:** Estou utilizando o `jqGrid(4.54)`, e também implementei o `SubGrid`, após abrir o `SubGrid`, é necessário exportar o conteúdo da tabela aberta.

**Pergunta:** Existe um modo de implementar um botão ou um link dentro do `SubGrid`?

Veja abaixo o código do meu `SubGrid`:

```js
 var subgrid_table_id;
       subgrid_table_id = subgrid_id+"_t";
       jQuery("#"+subgrid_id).html("<table id='"+subgrid_table_id+"' class='scroll'></table><div id='paginacaoSub'></div>");
       jQuery("#"+subgrid_table_id).jqGrid({
          url: urlRelatorioInterno,
          datatype: 'json',
          mtype: 'POST',
          colModel: [
            {name:"dataHora", index:"dataHora", jsonmap:"dataHora", label:"Data e Hora", sortable: true, sorttype: "date"},
            {name:"tipoSolicitacao",index:"tipoSolicitacao",jsonmap:"tipoSolicitacao",label:"Tipo Solicitacao", sortable: true, sorttype: "int"},
            {name:"statusSolicitacao",index:"statusSolicitacao",jsonmap:"statusSolicitacao",label:"Status Solicitacao",  sortable: true, sorttype: "text"},
            {name:"numeroSolicitacao",index:"numeroSolicitacao",jsonmap:"numeroSolicitacao",label:"Numero Solicitacao",  sortable: true, sorttype: "int"},           
            {name:"numeroCartao",index:"numeroCartao",jsonmap:"numeroCartao",label:"Numero Cartao",  sortable: true, sorttype: "int"},
            {name:"nomeSegurado",index:"nomeSegurado",jsonmap:"nomeSegurado",label:"Nome Segurado",  sortable: true, sorttype: "text"},
            {name:"codigoReferenciado",index:"codigoReferenciado",jsonmap:"codigoReferenciado",label:"Codigo Referenciado",  sortable: true, sorttype: "int"},
            {name:"nomeReferenciado",index:"nomeReferenciado",jsonmap:"nomeReferenciado",label:"Nome Referenciado",  sortable: true, sorttype: "text"},
            {name:"senha",index:"senha",jsonmap:"senha",label:"Senha",  sortable: true, sorttype: "text"},           
            {name:"canalSolicitacao",index:"canalSolicitacao",jsonmap:"canalSolicitacao",label:"Canal Solicitacao",  sortable: true, sorttype: "int"}],

          pager: "#paginacaoSub",
          scroll: 1,
          width: 1100,
          height: 240,
          rowNum:10,
          rowList: true,
          loadonce:true
       });
```

Comment: A sua pergunta é como implementar uma função de exportar dentro do subgrid ou de como adicionar um botão dentro do subgrid?

Comment: Acho que seria como colocar um botão/link dentro desse subGrid. Eu adicionaria uma coluna no JSON com o link, o problema seria achar o parâmetros de filtro.

Comment: Extamente, é necessário inserir um botão de exportar para excel e pdf no conteudo aberto pelo subGrid. Gostaria de saber se há algum modo simples de implementar essa exportação.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pessoal achei um modo fácil de inserir os botões no subgrid. O jqGrid ja disponibiliza um modo para inserir atraves de uma função do jqGrid "navButtonAdd". Abaixo se encontra o código do subGrid junto ao código dos botões.

```
var urlTipoSolicitacao = "?filtro.tipoSolicitacao="+$('#respostaRelatorio').jqGrid('getRowData', row_id).tipoSolicitacao;
       var subgrid_table_id;
       subgrid_table_id = subgrid_id+"_t";
       jQuery("#"+subgrid_id).html("<table id='"+subgrid_table_id+"' class='scroll'></table><div id='paginacaoSub'></div>");
       jQuery("#"+subgrid_table_id).jqGrid({
          url: urlRelatorioInterno + urlTipoSolicitacao,
          datatype: 'json',
          mtype: 'POST',
          colModel: [
            {name:"dataHora", index:"dataHora", jsonmap:"dataHora", label:"Data e Hora", sortable: true, sorttype: "date"},
            {name:"tipoSolicitacao",index:"tipoSolicitacao",jsonmap:"tipoSolicitacao",label:"Tipo Solicitacao", sortable: true, sorttype: "int"},
            {name:"statusSolicitacao",index:"statusSolicitacao",jsonmap:"statusSolicitacao",label:"Status Solicitacao",  sortable: true, sorttype: "text"},
            {name:"numeroSolicitacao",index:"numeroSolicitacao",jsonmap:"numeroSolicitacao",label:"Numero Solicitacao",  sortable: true, sorttype: "int"},           
            {name:"numeroCartao",index:"numeroCartao",jsonmap:"numeroCartao",label:"Numero Cartao",  sortable: true, sorttype: "int"},
            {name:"nomeSegurado",index:"nomeSegurado",jsonmap:"nomeSegurado",label:"Nome Segurado",  sortable: true, sorttype: "text"},
            {name:"codigoReferenciado",index:"codigoReferenciado",jsonmap:"codigoReferenciado",label:"Codigo Referenciado",  sortable: true, sorttype: "int"},
            {name:"nomeReferenciado",index:"nomeReferenciado",jsonmap:"nomeReferenciado",label:"Nome Referenciado",  sortable: true, sorttype: "text"},
            {name:"senha",index:"senha",jsonmap:"senha",label:"Senha",  sortable: true, sorttype: "text"},           
            {name:"canalSolicitacao",index:"canalSolicitacao",jsonmap:"canalSolicitacao",label:"Canal Solicitacao",  sortable: true, sorttype: "int"}],
          pager: "#paginacaoSub",
          scroll: 1,
          width: 1100,
          height: 135,
          rowNum:5,
          rowList: true,
          loadonce:true
         }).jqGrid('navGrid', '#paginacaoSub', {
                           add: false,
                           edit: false,
                           del : false,
                           search: false,
                           refresh: false
                             }).jqGrid('navButtonAdd', '#paginacaoSub',{ 
                           caption: "Exportar Excel",
                           onClickButton: function(){ 
                                window.location.href = urlExportarExcelInterno + urlTipoSolicitacao;
                               }, 
                           position: "first"
                             }).jqGrid('navButtonAdd', '#paginacaoSub',{
                           caption: "Exportar PDF",
                           onClickButton: function(){ 
                               window.location.href = urlExportarPdfInterno + urlTipoSolicitacao;
                                   }, 
                           position: "first"

                             });
                      };
```